# Media9 package: pause video without mediabutton

Tags: media9

I have a media9 video embedded in a beamer class document as follows:

```
\includemedia[
        label=Cor_T,
        width=\linewidth,
        height=\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        addresource=Plots/Cor_movie.mp4,
        flashvars={source=Plots/Cor_movie.mp4
                &loop=true
                &scaleMode=letterbox}
    ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

Currently when I click on the video it starts playing. I would like to have it that when I click again, it pauses. Is there a way to do this without adding an extra media button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the mouse as follows:

- Press the mouse button on the video. It pauses immediately
- Keep it pressed while explaining details to the audience
- Release the button to continue playback

To pause it permanently, proceed as follows:

- Move the mouse off the video while keeping the mouse button pressed
- Release the mouse button outside the video area
- Continue by clicking on the video again