# Start, pause, resume and replay an embedded video

Tags: media9, embedding, video

I experiment with an example from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-media9-to-include-videos-files/yvdwwvpknjkk to embed a video using the `media9` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
    % using a .mp4; downloaded from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9iXD2-hbJM                                                                                                                                 
    \includemedia[width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.6\linewidth,activate=pageopen,
    passcontext,
    transparent,
    addresource=penguins.mp4,
    flashvars={source=penguins.mp4}]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{document}
```

The video works with the `okular` viewer, not `evince`. `Acrobat Reader` throws a `3D parsing error`.

However, the video plays only once upon opening the document. I have no ability to replay, pause and resume the video. Also clicking the video with the mouse as explained in [Media9 package: pause video without mediabutton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306699/media9-package-pause-video-without-mediabutton?rq=1) does not work.

How to implement these additional functionalities?

Comment: Support of embedded  media is very limited in non-Adobe PDF viewers. Evince doesn't support it at all, Okular with little functionality only. Perhaps, playing the video in an external application is the better option for Okular and Evince: `\href{run:penguins.mp4}{Click!}`..

Comment: @AlexG, could you please provide a complete example (in answer)?